# AS3 BitmapData CopyPixels with alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, rendering, bitmapdata

I am trying to copy the pixels of a bitmap into BitmapData at a transparency of lets say .5 but i can't seem to find any reference to this anywhere on google or here!

i have my standard copy pixel code

`_bitmapData.copyPixels(_bitmaps.vault[BitmapNames.BITMAPNAME], SCREENRECT, _drawPoint, null, null, true);`

I can see that the first null value i pass is a BitmapData labelled `alphaBitmapData:BitmapData` so i'm assuming it has something to do with that, but i cant work it out!

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accepted Will Kru's answer as the answer (though only theory based) below is the code used to put the method behind the madness!!

`var alphaBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, toARGB(0x000000, (.5 * 255)));`

`_bitmapData.copyPixels(_bitmaps.vault[BitmapNames.BITMAP], _drawRect, _drawPoint, alphaBitmap, null, true);`

toARGB function found here [alpha + RGB -> ARGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150046/alpha-rgb-argb)

Comment: Yes this will work too. Copypixels will fetch the color values from the bitmap you pass to the first parameter and the alpha values from the bitmap you pass to the 4th parameter. In my answer I assumed your sourcebitmap would contain the alpha values so you could use it for both parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Following [this link](http://www.designswan.com/archives/the-function-of-mergealpha-in-copypixels.html) you will find some explanation about the variables.

In short, when you set the last parameter (mergeAlpha:Boolean) to true, the function will take the 4th parameter (alphaBitmap:BitmapData) into account when copying the pixels, effectively using the alpha of the alphaBitmap to merge the copied pixels. So you should pass the same bitmap you use for the first parameter to the 4th parameter, set the 5th parameter (alphaPoint:Point) accordingly and set the last parameter to true.

Comment: So you can only define the alpha of a bitmap at creation. I want to copy the bitmap to another BitmapData at .5 transparency at frame 1, then on frame 2 when i redraw the whole bitmap i want to draw it on the BitmapData at .4, then .3 ..... (as an example) but from what i can undestand from the artical you posted, you cannot do this?

Comment: You would just keep the original bitmaps in memory and use those to recreate the bitmap you want using the desired alpha values at every frame.

Comment: I am storing in memory, I didn't understand how to apply the theory into code. I have now worked it out! something like this worked

`var test:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_drawRect.width, _drawRect.height, true, toARGB(0x000000, (.5 * 255)));
    _bitmapData.copyPixels(_bitmaps.vault[BitmapNames.LEAPJUMPLINE], _drawRect, _drawPoint, test, null, true);
}

private function toARGB(rgb:uint, newAlpha:uint):uint{
    var argb:uint = 0;
    argb = (rgb);
    argb += (newAlpha<<24);
    return argb;
}`

Comment: thanks, the documentation writes **alphaBitmapData: A secondary alpha BitmapData object source.** It's really not self explanatory